# Restrict access to and Highlight Tab in Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, vbscript, ms-office, office-2010

I am working on a form with 3 tabs and what I would like to do is either restrict access of other tabs until user provides information on Tab Page 1 or make the other tabs invisible until User provides correct information on Tab Page 1. I am new to building forms in MS Access. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to pages of the tab control, and you can refer to controls on the tab control by name:

```
Me.Page24.Visible = (Not IsNull(Me.ID))
```

There is no need to reference a page to reference a control on that page.